# Magento cart Url change

Tags: magento, url, phpmyadmin

Hello i have changed my base url from admin panel and now i can't access admin panel, please help me to resolve this problem.

I have tried to change it from php my admin but it is not the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to change base url directly from database. Search `base_url` in `path` column of `core_config_data` table. It will show you all the both secure and unsecure URL. 
Update records with your correct website URL like: http://www.example.com/.

Remove cache and session folder and open your website. It will work.

If you are using multi stores with different URL, there are more than two entities in the `core_config_data` table. So you can search the URL that need to change in `value` column as well.

Comment: Clearing the session folder is not necessary, the cache folder is enough (`/var/cache/`).